# How to create a file folder for use with Listen Audiobook player

Tags: file-system, motorola-moto-g, file-management, media-files, audiobooks

I can't figure out how to use this Listen book player, I've Installed.

First I see this.

[image: first screen]

Hitting OK, I see this:

[image: second screen]

I can't understand how to tell it where to find my books.

I've downloaded one already, it is in downloads. I can select it (outside of the Listen app) but I can't figure out how to create a folder in which to put it.

I think I'm missing some basic file navigation ideas. I've used Android for over a year, but have not needed to move files to specific locations.

**Edit:** I've installed a File Manager, and added a directory, but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the overflow menu button in the upper right.  Select the show storage option.  There will now be a new item below the Recent menu item in the slide out drawer for the devices storage.